# What is the equivalent of NPP_NewStream,NPP_WriteReady,NPP_Write,NPP_DestroyStream for ACTIVEX controls in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, npapi

i'm trying to enclose an ACTIVEX in another ACTIVEX which is supposed to be invoked by Internet Explorer when a particular Mime-type is seen on the webpage. I have implemented something similar for NPAPI and i could see how the browser transfer the data to the NPAPI plugin by using the functions "NPP_NewStream,NPP_WriteReady,NPP_Write,NPP_DestroyStream". However for ACTIVEX i'm not able to understand how the transfer of data from the Internet Explorer browser toward the ACTIVEX happens. I have done several research, gone through Internet Explorer architecture document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but couldn't figure out.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Giovanni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) has a BrowserStreams wrapper which has implementations both in ActiveX and on NPAPI; there are not direct equivilents, but with WinHTTP you can do the same things on ActiveX.

The code is under the new BSD license, so take a look and steal what you need -- alternately, FireBreath might not be a bad way to go for building your system.

Primary files to look at:

- https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/axstream.h
- https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/axstream.cpp
- https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/axstream_impl.h
- https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/axstream_impl.cpp

Comment: Hi Taxilian, thanks for the answer, i went through firebreath code and i see that the WinHTTP code is actually under #ifdef 0 so i wonder how the download from the ACTIVEX can be initiated. Using Firebreath will certainly allow me to avoid to know this details but for the application i'm developing i need more to understand the protocol first. Any pointer to a documentation in this area? MSDN has documentation but is fragmented, and not easy to follow.

Comment: sorry, it seems I misremembered; it seems you are right and it uses wininet because proxy support is better. I don't know of any better docs, but that code works so it should be useable sample code

Comment: Thanks a lot. Taxilian, very helpful as usual.